# VBA- Alter a different cell with multiple cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA in excel, I am wanting to incorporate the formula located in column "O", shown below, for all B rows that have a value starting at B9. Please reference the image.

=""&D9&" "&I9&" (MK NO. "&B9&")"

[image]

Comment: I definitely understand where you are coming from. I have done my research on here, and VBA is not my forte. Im simply asking for help so I can progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what your are looking for.

```
Sub Pasteformula()

Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim c As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set LookupRange = Range("B9:B500") ' Set range in Column B

For Each c In LookupRange 'Loop through range
    If c.Value <> "" Then 'If value in B is empty then
        Cells(c.Row, 15).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=""""&RC[-11]&"" ""&RC[-6]&"" (MK NO. ""&RC[-13]&"")""" 'Apply formula
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the range and enter the formula, then change the range to values.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("O9:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(D9,"" "",I9,"" (MK NO. "",B9,"")"")"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

from your narrative I get that you already have the proper formula in O9, hence you could use `AutoFill()` method of `Range` object:

```
Range("O9").AutoFill Range("B9", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Offset(,13)
```